# Trying to identify why com.apple.Safari.Safebrowsing.Service has network traffic, despite not using Safari

Tags: macos, safari

Just noticed it today, and I got very curious, as I don't use Safari as a browser. I am aware that safebrowsing is a locally queried list, and that it does get updated. However, given that google are the ones that maintain it, Chrome wouldn't do so through safari, so I can't understand why I would have seen this traffic. Only thing I was really able to identify was using sudo lsof -i to get the following address: gbmnc1-vip-bx-003.aaplimg.com, and for some reason it has written 124.3MB to disk, but that's about it.

I can't find anything in the console logs that would indicate why this is occurring, and I am not sure what terminal commands to run. I am aware Safari is integrated with MacOS, but I cannot recall having seen this before.

Edit: Only other thing is that, when looking at the energy tab of activity monitor, and then expanding Google Chrome, com.apple.safariservices was there. However, today it doesn't seem to be. Why would Google Chrome randomly need to use that component?

Comment: A number of other apps use the Safari "engine" to display their content, this would explain that usage. Disabling **all** of Safari-related processes on your Mac is likely not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that Chrome uses com.apple.safariservices if you do certain things, like upload a file. From here, related processes to it seem to run, like com.apple.safari.safebrowsing.service, which then seems to have some automated tasks to run.

Answer (score -1):

Let disable that service.

It runs in background and check for new data interval, so if there are update then it download and write to disk. It's annoyed.

I disabled it, it save CPUs and data which is write to SSD. After that, browsing is slowing by some how, both Safari and Chrome, or my network is just slow in time.

I will track it and give some update.

Update: It starts by some how even I disabled it @_@